# Check in reflection if type is primitive or type is object

Tags: java, reflection, primitive-types, generic-programming

Im using the following code to find class members in reflection that are primitive and some object ,my question is there is a way to identify if field is type primitive ,object ,class reference because i want to call to specific method according to the type.
for example if field is primitive call to handlePrimitive if field type other type reference (in the example below SalesOrderItemPK primaryKey; )call to method handleClassReferance etc

just of understanding  i need to get the class and invistigate it and create data according to the member type...

```
for (Object clsObj : listClsObj) {
        Field[] declaredFields = clsObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        numOfEntries = 1;
        do {
            Object newInstance = clsObj.getClass().newInstance();

            for (Field field : declaredFields) {

                // Get member name & types

                Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
                Type genericType = field.getGenericType();
                String fieldTypeName = fieldType.getName();
                String memberName = field.getName();


                if (genericType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) genericType;
                    for (Type typeOfReferance : pt.getActualTypeArguments()) {

                        String classTypeName = typeOfReferance.toString();
                        String[] parts = classTypeName.split(" ");
                        memberReferance = parts[1];
```

here i want to call to specific method that can handle fields according to the data types

```
public static SwitchInputType<?> switchInput(final String typeName, final String memberName, final int cnt) {
    if (typeName.equals("java.lang.String")) {
        return new SwitchInputType<String>(new String(memberName + " " + cnt));
    } else if (typeName.equals("char")) {
        return new SwitchInputType<Character>(new Character('a'));
```

the class for example should look like this and I need to know for primaryKey key to create an object.

```
@Entity
public class SalesOrderItem 
{
    @EmbeddedId
    SalesOrderItemPK primaryKey; 
    private String ProductId;
    private String Notes;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't call `.toString()`, but instead cast `Type` to `Class`, you get `.isPrimitive()`

Comment: and btw the code is entered to this lines when for instance we have member in the class type other class for instance :private List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<Job>();

Comment: for example i find with this code if type int is primitive but how should i know for type string which type is it ?

Comment: I didn't get that question

Comment: I could do `field.getType().isPrimitive()` without the additional cast to `Class` in Java 1.6 I think.